# Glassfish v3 client. What is gf-client.jar?

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb

From what i have read, gf-client.jar, since Glassfish 3, is the only jar you need to include on your client side since it's supposed to include the **javaee.jar** from Glassfish installation. But when i add gf-client.jar to my standalone java application acting as a client, i can't refer to anything from the standard Java EE, no javax.persistence, no javax.ejb etc...

My question is why? I'm simply adding gf-client.jar to my client, is it enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open the `gf-client.jar` (with a compression util like winrar) and open the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` you can see in the `Class-Path:` property all the libs that needs.

If your client app doesn't have all this libs (the required one for your app not all of them) the `gf-client.jar` is useless.